# Why can't python scripts be executed with inconsistant tabs and spaces?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, editor, atom-editor, indentation

I want to understand why you can't write a python script with a mixture of tabs and spaces for indenting. When you try to run a script with the mixture of tabs and spaces in the same line, it throws an error. I thought tabs become spaces once it goes through the compiler. So why does it matter?

Is it likely that this will ever get fixed or is there a way around this? I know most people use an editor that takes care of indentation consistency. I use two editors, both Sublime and Atom and both still generate scripts with this inconsistency and throw errors.

It seems like a simple oversight. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Most editors should have an option to replace tabs by spaces during editing.

Comment: Indentation should line up visually. With tabs, the indentation whitespace is external  - its whatever you've programmed your editor to use. If I have 2 lines, `\t\tprint(1)` and `\t    \tprint(2)`, are they at the same indenation level? They'd line up with tabs set to 8 spaces, but not with tabs set to 4. A common bug is using spaces for indentation because you want it to look consistent for all viewers but using an editor that doesn't convert tabs to spaces. This is a bug that hits many people and its been argued for a long time that you should only go one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs and spaces are different characters(different ascii values) and are not equivalent in any way except editors can detect tabs and replace them with 2 or 4 spaces depending on editor's configuration.

Solution to your problem would be changing configuration of editors and staying consistent on either tabs or spaces.